# How to solve for a trigonometric inequality $2\cos(2x)\cos(x)+\cos(2x)\gt0$

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone please help me solve this inequality:

$2\cos(2x)\cos(x)+\cos(2x)\gt0$

I know how to get the values for $x$, but what I don't understand is how the answer is $0 < x < 45$ and $120 < x < 135$. How do you get these answers?

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions, so I'm assuming you only need to find solutions in the range $0º < x < 180º$. To find which direction the inequalities are pointing, you need to make a sign diagram.

Comment: I saw this question yesterday, do not delete and repost same question please

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

If we work with range $0º<x<180º$, then

$2\cos(2x)\cos(x)+\cos(2x)=\cos(2x)(2\cos(x)+1)=(\cos(x)-\sin(x))(2\cos(x)+1)>0$.

Now notice that

\begin{align}
 2\cos(x)+1  \begin{cases} >0 & \mbox{if } 0<x<45º \\ <0 & \mbox{if }180º>x>45º\end{cases} 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 \cos(x)-\sin(x)\begin{cases} >0 & \mbox{if } 0<x<120º \\ <0 & \mbox{if }120º<x<180º\end{cases} 
\end{align}

Then combining the above inequalities:

\begin{align}
 (\cos(x)-\sin(x))(2\cos(x)+1)>0  \qquad \mbox{if } 0<x<45º \mbox{ and } 120º<x<180º.
\end{align}